# Store Double array in a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, reportviewer

How to store a double array in one column (field) of a DataTable?

I want to have 2 data fields to keep in a row, the first one being an integer which is the ID of the product and the second one being a double array which contains all the different prices the product has had (evolution of the product's prices). How can I store these 365 prices of the product in the same row. Maybe I should use an array `price`:

```
dtPriceOfProduct.Rows.Add(product_id, price)
```

where `price` is an array of all the prices the product with `product_id` can have. I want to have 1x5,000 rows not 365x5,000.

Currently I am storing data like this

```
int product_id;
double[] price = new double[];
```

and I create a new row in my DataTable for each price of the same product

```
foreach(double price_data in price)
{
    dtPriceOfProduct.Rows.Add(product_id, price_data)
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify this line? `How can I store these 365 prices of the product in the same row` so you want to create a table with `365 columns`  and a single row? or you want to list the whole array in a single cell?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i store the array for the product into the same row.

IMO what you want to achieve is not a good idea. But if you insist that you *still* want to continue with that design, I suggest you use a dictionary with the item id as the key and the array as the value*. Then serialize the said dictionary before saving into the said `DataTable`.

*something like this perhaps?

```
Dictionary<int, double[]> priceHistory = new Dictionary<int, double[]>();
priceHistory.Add(id, price);
```

for the serialization/deserialization, kindly refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733200/how-to-serialize-class-to-database-instead-of-file-system-c-sharp)

Comment: If this is a bad idea, what do you suggest me? I have to use a datable because, after, i use data into ReportViewer to display the price's evolution

Comment: What I could suggest right now is do pivoting on `DataTable` (i.e. Have multiple rows with the same id and perhaps different day and price.) You may see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624676/database-pivoting-what-is-the-purpose) for more information. I also believe this will work on `DataTables` too. You may have to do querying on your reports, but it's basically the same thing.

Comment: You should really be using a related table for your prices. A google search will easily find plenty of examples and advice. Here's something to get you started: https://chsakell.com/2013/06/22/ado-net-working-with-dataset-datatable-datacolumn-datarow-and-datarelations/